# Shutting up log4j for good

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

Im using a 3rd party jar that uses log4j and spams really way too much (makes eclipse crash), is there a way to wipe all logging as if log4j never existed in the first place? programmatically or by project setup anything is fine as long as it stfu.

i tried

```
List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
for ( Logger logger : loggers ) {
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

But doesnt compile in my setup:

```
LogManager.getCurrentLoggers() and 
LogManager.getRootLogger() do not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2 uses multiple contexts. Adapting the above code:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext();
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();
Collection<LoggerConfig> loggers = config.getLoggers().values();
for(LoggerConfig cfg: loggers) {
  cfg.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

Comment: ok, how do i get loggerContext and configuration? or even a list of all running loggerContext(s) and configuration(s)

Comment: it doesnt compile like the above example, im using log4j 2.1 , should i try with previous versions?

Comment: LogManager.getContext() method doesnt exist config.getLoggers() method doesnt exist The type org.apache.logging.log4j.Level cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: If possible please upgrade to the latest version. 2.8 will be released in a few days.

Comment: Are you importing org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager as opposed to java.util.logging.LogManager? Because it certainly does exist: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getContext()